# Update record in 'x' days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I have tasks that my users go through and finish one-by-one and record the result. Depending on the result, the task may have to be put on hold for 'x' number of days, and then after 'x' days, it becomes available again. Sometimes it goes back in the task queue for ONLY 'y' days, and then expires (task.active=0)

What is the best way to achieve this functionality using Rails 3? I am using Postgre.

Answer (score 2):

Make a model attribute `inactive_until` which is either null or a date in the future.  Then add a scope to your model, `active`, which simply checks if that field is `nil` or `< Time.now`

Now to make someone inactive for a time period, set `inactive_until` to a date in the future.

Comment: For more efficient and readable queries it can be worth making `active_until` a `NOT NULL` field and using a distant future date. If Rails and the Pg gem support infinite dates use `+infinity` as the date; otherwise use the biggest date Rail and the Pg gem do support. This only makes sense if a fairly large proportion of your records have a non-null `active_until` field; if only a smaller fraction have `active_until` set you can use `null` for the unset ones and create a partial index on `(active_until) WHERE (active_until IS NOT NULL)`